# Multiple options using np.where and not just binary

Tags: python, pandas

Assuming I have grouped US states into lists:

```
list1 = ['TX','FL','OR']
list2 = ['AL','MA','NJ']
list3 = ['WA','PA','GA']
```

I have over 15 lists covering all 50 states, but for the sake of brevity, I will keep it down to 3 lists.

I have the following dataframe df:

```
State    abbrev     produce        goods    service   

Alabama      AL            5          10        15   
Texas        TX            7          17        27   
Florida      FL            2          73        13   
Georgia      GA            12         65        20    
New Jersey   NJ            65         26        11
```

I want to create a column called final_delivery, which is equal to `produce` if the state is in `list1`, `goods` if the state is in `list2`, and `service` if the state is in `list3`

```
State    abbrev     produce        goods    service   final_delivery  

Alabama      AL            5          10        15               10  
Texas        TX            7          17        27                7   
Florida      FL            2          73        13                2  
Georgia      GA            12         65        20               20    
New Jersey   NJ            65         26        11               26
```

I have tried the following:

```
df["final_delivery"] = np.where(df['abbrev'].isin(list1), df['produce'], "")
```

but it replaces the values to missing when I try to move on to filling the column based on list2 and list3.

Comment: Hey I put an answer out there that is based on nested `np.where` but then went back and looked at your question again where you say you have 15 lists.  A 15 level nested `np.where` would work but would be unwieldy and you'd need like a program to actually build that.

Comment: Is a loop ok for you?

Comment: @KevinChoonLiangYew yes, a loop would be fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create the mapping first then doing value position slice

```
mapping = {z : x  for x, y in zip(['produce','goods','service'], [list1,list2,list3]) for z in y}
df['final_delivery'] = df.to_numpy()[np.arange(df.shape[0]),
                                     df.columns.get_indexer(df.abbrev.map(mapping))]
df
Out[533]: 
       State abbrev  produce  goods  service final_delivery
0    Alabama     AL        5     10       15             10
1      Texas     TX        7     17       27              7
2    Florida     FL        2     73       13              2
3    Georgia     GA       12     65       20             20
4  NewJersey     NJ       65     26       11             26
```

Answer (score 1):

You could build an inverted index that points to the function that you want to execute.  This easily scales to 15 lists.

**Inverted Index**

```
si = pd.Series([0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2], index=['TX','FL','OR','AL','MA','NJ','WA','PA','GA']).sort_index()
print(si)

AL    1
FL    0
GA    2
MA    1
NJ    1
OR    0
PA    2
TX    0
WA    2
```

**Function Map**

```
fmap = {
    0: lambda x: x['produce'],
    1: lambda x: x['goods'],
    2: lambda x: x['service']
}
```

**Apply it**

```
df.apply(lambda x: fmap[si.at[x['abbrev']]](x), axis=1)
```

**Result**

```
0    10
1     7
2     2
3    20
4    26
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you can create a column with `np.nan`

```
df['final_delivery'] = np.nan
```

Next, for the sake of simplicity and for loop, I will put your lists into a nested list.

```
new_list = [list1, list2, list3]
```

You can adjust the `new_list` based on the order of your column, because I was thinking of using the order of `df.columns` to facilitate the for loop.

```
for abb, col in zip(newlist,df.columns[2:-1]):
    df['final_delivery'].loc[df['abbrev'].isin(abb)] = df[col].loc[df['abbrev'].isin(abb)]

df
        State abbrev  produce  goods  service  final_delivery
0     Alabama     AL        5     10       15            10.0
1       Texas     TX        7     17       27             7.0
2     Florida     FL        2     73       13             2.0
3     Georgia     GA       12     65       20            20.0
4  New Jersey     NJ       65     26       11            26.0
```

Comment: It's not a gracious way in Pandas compared to the other answers but this can help solving your problem too :)

Answer (score 0):

The following helps maintain the integrity of the data frame column:

```
df["final_delivery"] = np.where(df['abbrev'].isin(list1), df['produce'], "")
df["final_delivery"] = np.where(df['abbrev'].isin(list1), df['goods'], df["final_delivery"])
df["final_delivery"] = np.where(df['abbrev'].isin(list1), df['service'], df["final_delivery"])
```